# Sql Server 2012: How to find elements that are not in the list

Tags: sql-server, list, search, element

I have a list of countries that i want to find which one is not in the table.

Lets say that my list is like this: ('Greece', 'Chile', 'Hawaii') and in the table already exist Greece and Chile and not exist Hawaii.

How can i make the query to find what is missing from the list i provide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put your criteria in another table and then use an outer join. For example:

```
DECLARE @Test as table(Cnty varchar(50))

insert into @Test(Cnty) values ('Greece')
insert into @Test(Cnty) values ('Chile')


SELECT tmp2.Cntry FROM (
SELECT * FROM @Test t
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 'Greece' Cntry UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Chile' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Hawaii') Tmp
        ON t.Cnty = tmp.Cntry
) tmp2
WHERE cnty is null
```

Comment: thank you but my problem is that there is not only 3 elements in the list so i can't insert one by one.

Comment: There are several ways you can build your table. For example, I have a Table-valued Function I created that converts a delimited string into a table of values.  If this still wont work, please give more information about your requirements.